# Making a GET request JSON with parameters using Python

Tags: python, json, get

I was wondering how do I make a GET request to a specific url with two query parameters? These query parameters contain two id numbers
So far I have:

```
import json, requests
url = 'http://'
requests.post(url)
```

But they gave me query paramters first_id=###  and  last_id=###. I don't know how to include these parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make a GET request you need the [`get()` method](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.get), for parameters use `params` argument:

```
response = requests.get(url, params={'first_id': 1, 'last_id': 2})
```

---

If the response is of a JSON content type, you can use the [`json()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response.json) shortcut method to get it loaded into a Python object for you:

```
data = response.json()
print(data)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! How do I acquire the the JSON response itself? Apologies this is the first time I'm doing a GET request

Comment: is it response.json? so print response.json?

Comment: ah I see! Thank you!